# Equivalent of C's pointer to pointer in Java

Tags: java, c, pointers

I am unable to pass **pointer to pointer** as an argument to the function in Java.I know that Java don't have pointers instead we pass reference to objects. I want to know how this is done. 
To clear my doubt I am pasting the code snippet of the program that I am implementing.

In the following program I am calling a method "Partition" from the method "QuickSortRecur".
As I work on C for most of the time I don't know how to send the parameters **newHead** and **newEnd** as **pointer to pointer**.

I have also mentioned the C Equivalent of the below lines , I just want to know how can I implement the same in Java?

Java :

```
public ListNode Partition(ListNode lhead,ListNode lend,ListNode newHead,ListNode newEnd){
         ---------
         ---------
         ---------

    }
public ListNode QuickSortRecur(ListNode lhead,ListNode lend){
    ListNode newHead=null;
    ListNode newEnd=null;
    ListNode pivot;     

    pivot=Partition(lhead,lend,newHead,newEnd);
    if(newHead==null)
            {
            System.out.println("This is not updated ");
            }
       }
```

C Equivalent of Above Signature:

```
struct node *partition(struct node *head, struct node *end,
                       struct node **newHead, struct node **newEnd){
}

struct node *quickSortRecur(struct node *head, struct node *end)
{
struct node *pivot = partition(head, end, &newHead, &newEnd);
}
```

Comment: You can create container objects that contain objects; a little like a pointer to a pointer. But its probably easier if you describe what you need to do rather than how you think you'd do it

Comment: There are referances in Java.If you assign a referance to another referance they referance to same object.

Comment: I think the best advise I can give is forget everything about pointers from c, java references have a passing resemblance to pointers but work very differently (mostly that you don't worry about them being references). Consider the logic the pointer to pointer was trying to accomplish and recreate that in java

Comment: Can anyone tell how this can be done, I havent found anything constructive, Well I am learning . If you guys know a lot of about Java then I would wish someone to explain clearly.I am finding Richard Tingle's Comment useful

Comment: @Nilesh is your objective to send the "result" of the function back into several of the arguments you pass to the function? If so you can mutate (change) the object you pass (if you pass anything but a primative (int, double etc) you are passing a reference but its best not to worry about that too much. As an example if you passed a Vector3d you could change its x, y and z and that would change the x, y and z of the underlying object (which may have many references)

Comment: @RichardTingle: Finally I am able to resolve the issue. Thanks for help.I have posted the answer too.

Comment: @Nilesh glad I could help. Iooks ike you've got the idea, the internals of an object can be modified from wherever you have a reference (assuming appropriate methods). Hope you enjoy java (I am personally a big fan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering C's pointer a rough equivalent to Java's reference, a rough equivalent to a pointer to pointer would be a mutable class encapsulating a reference.

For example, you can build something like this:

```
class ListNodeReference {
    private ListNode node;
    public ListNode getNode() {
        return node;
    }
    public void setNode(ListNode theNode) {
        node = theNode;
    }
}
```

You can pass `ListNodeReference` to a function that can get or set it using its get and set methods, much in the same way as C program uses single dereference to get to the actual pointer (double dereference would happen automatically when your code accesses `ListNode`, because it is already a reference object).

Keep in mind that this is a very rough equivalent, not a one-for-one substitution: for example, there is no way to pass back an array of `ListNode` objects using a `ListNodeReference`.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve issue through this ..

```
     public class LinkedList {
    public ListNode head;
    private ListNode newHead;
    private ListNode newEnd;

    LinkedList(){
        head = null;
        newHead=null;
        newEnd=null;
    }

    public ListNode getNewEnd() {
        return this.newEnd;
    }
    public void setNewEnd(ListNode newEnd) {
       this.newEnd=newEnd;
    }

    public ListNode getNewHead(){
        return this.newHead;
    }

    public void setNewHead(ListNode newHead){
        this.newHead=newHead;
    }

    public ListNode getHead(){
        return this.head;
    }
    public void setHead(ListNode head){
        this.head=head;
    }

public ListNode Partition(ListNode lhead,ListNode lend,LinkedList Ref){
        ListNode pivot=lend;
        ListNode End=lend;
        ListNode curr=lhead;
        //ListNode temp=null;
        ListNode previous=null;

        ListNode newHead=Ref.getNewHead();
        ListNode newEnd=Ref.getNewEnd();
                --------------------------
        -----implementation -----
                --------------------------

        Ref.setNewEnd(newEnd);
        Ref.setNewHead(newHead);
        return pivot;

        }
    public ListNode QuickSortRecur(ListNode lhead,ListNode lend){
        ListNode newHead=null;
        ListNode newEnd=null;
        ListNode pivot;     
        LinkedList linkRef=new LinkedList();

        pivot=Partition(lhead,lend,linkRef);
        newHead=linkRef.getNewHead();
        newEnd=linkRef.getNewEnd();




        return newHead;
    }


}
```